# Lodash help on filtering using a search term and multiple property names

Tags: javascript, lodash, angularjs-filter

I wish to search on multiple columns however all the code I could find on the internet was restricted on a single search term that would search multiple columns. I wish to filter on multiple columns by multiple search terms

data:

```
var propertynames = ['firstName','lastName'];
var data = [
  {
    "city":"Irwin town",
    "address":"1399 Cecil Drive",
    "lastName":"Auer",
    "firstName":"Wanda"
  },
  {
    "city":"Howell haven"
    "address":"168 Arnoldo Light"
    "lastName":"Balistreri",
    "firstName":"Renee"
  }
];
var searchTerm = 'Wanda Auer';
```

Should result in an array that filtered out the 2nd object.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've created two solutions for your question. The first one is do exactly what you need: filters collection by two fields. The second one is more flexible, because it allows filter by any multiple fields.

First solution:

```js
function filterByTwoFields(coll, searchFilter) {
  return _.filter(coll, function(item) {
    return (item.firstName + ' ' + item.lastName) === searchTerm;
  });
}

var data = [
  {
    "city":"Irwin town",
    "address":"1399 Cecil Drive",
    "lastName":"Auer",
    "firstName":"Wanda"
  },
  {
    "city":"Howell haven",
    "address":"168 Arnoldo Light",
    "lastName":"Balistreri",
    "firstName":"Renee"
  }
];
var searchTerm = 'Wanda Auer';

var result = filterByTwoFields(data, searchTerm);
alert(JSON.stringify(result));
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lodash/lodash/master/dist/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Second solution:

```js
function filterByMultipleFields(coll, filter) {
  var filterKeys = _.keys(filter);
  return _.filter(coll, function(item) {
    return _.every(filterKeys, function(key) {
      return item[key] === filter[key];
    });
  });
}

var data = [
  {
    "city":"Irwin town",
    "address":"1399 Cecil Drive",
    "lastName":"Auer",
    "firstName":"Wanda"
  },
  {
    "city":"Howell haven",
    "address":"168 Arnoldo Light",
    "lastName":"Balistreri",
    "firstName":"Renee"
  }
];

var filter = {
  firstName: 'Wanda',
  lastName: 'Auer'
}
var result = filterByMultipleFields(data, filter);
alert(JSON.stringify(result));
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lodash/lodash/master/dist/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficent but it does the job. You might want to make an non case sensitive comparison on the property values:

```
var searchTerm = 'Wanda Auer',
    splitted = searchTerm.split(' ');

var result = data.filter(function(item){  
    return window.Object.keys(item).some(function(prop){
        if(propertynames.indexOf(prop) === -1)
            return;
        return splitted.some(function(term){
            return item[prop] === term;
      });
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3g626fb8/1/

Edit: Just noticed the Lodash tag. If you want to use it, the framework is using the same function names as the array prototype, i.e. `_.filter` and `_.some`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty straightforward lodash version:

```
var matchingRecords = _.filter(data, function (object) {
     return _(object)
         .pick(propertynames)
         .values()
         .intersection(searchTerm.split(' '))
         .size() > 0;
})
```

It filters the objects based on if any of the chosen property name values intersect with the search term tokens.